# Selenium IDE doesn't record once I stop and click record again

Tags: firefox, selenium-ide

Hi I met a strange issue which didn't show before when I use Selenium IDE to record some tests.

1. It doesn't get the url automatically when Selenium IDE is opened.
2. Which is the critical problem: once I stop the recording or play the test case which would stop the recording as well, it no longer records any additional action when I click again the recording button.

I'm not sure whether this is the problem of Selenium IDE or some problem with my Firefox. What I use is Selenium IDE 1.9.1, and Firefox 17, and there's no such problem when the first time I used it a couple of days ago.

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SeIDEReleaseNotes). 
Firefox 17 will be supported in upcoming selenium ide 1.10.0. So, better downgrade your firefox to 15 for better functioning of selenium ide 1.9.1

Comment: Yes I tried to downgrade to 15 but this issue still exists. I wonder whether there's any possibility that it's influenced by virus?

Comment: when you are recording for the second time, it will not record the base url if it is diffferent one from the first. But it will record the actions you do on the new page.

Comment: No I didn't turn to a new page. I still stay on the current page and just try to add new actions but it doesn't record any more once I click stop and click to record again.

Comment: I have just now tried the same with firefox nightly version 19 and selenium ide 1.9.1. it is working perfectly. probably you can try to uninstall selenium IDE add on and re install it and check. Good Luck !

Comment: Yes I tried reinstall both firefox and selenium ide add on but it was still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just for record, I have fixed the issue in Selenium IDE v2.3.0, which should be released soon. See http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5820